# Android notification when BLE device discovered

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

We are working on an Android app that makes GATT connection to BLE devices and writes some characteristics. Our current approach is to scan for devices (startLEScan on Android 4.3 and 4.4. devices and startScan on Android 5.0+) every few seconds and connect to device when discovered.

This solution works but it drains a lot of battery because we need to keep wake locks (or trigger alarm manager every few seconds) for the scanning to work when the phone is in sleep.

Is there an way that Android can notify the app when the BLE device is discovered instead of continuously scanning for devices?

iOS app works great because iOS wakes the app in background when there is any BLE device nearby, which saves a lot of battery. 
Wondering it there is something similar on Android to keep the battery under acceptable limit.

Just for reference, we have also tried the [Alt-Beacon](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library) library but found 
that it internally usages alarm manager and if we set alarm manager to trigger every 5 seconds, it consumes 7-8% battery every hour.

Comment: any solution on this?